# Show validation message, but clear value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I've been searching around and I'm not able to find an answer on what seems like a simple requirement:

With MVC Data Annotation validation, can you show the validation message ('must be a string with a maximum length of 5') in the validation summary or next to field, but clear the value of the text box (when validation fails).

I've tried to use `ModelState.Clear()` and `ModelState.Remove("CompanyName")`, but this clears *both* the value and validation message (validation state).

I'm asking this because recently we had a penetration test and one of the recommendations was to not *pre-populate* secure values (credit card number etc) if validation fails.  This is obviously a minor issue, but the recommendation was to not send the value back across the internet (from the server) if we didn't have to.

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(CompanyInput input)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Success");
    }
    //ModelState.Clear // clears both the value and validation message
    //ModelState.Remove("CompanyName") // same result
    return View(new CompanyInput());
}
```

And the view model:

```
public class CompanyInput
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And the view:

```
@model Test.Models.CompanyInput

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Company"))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
}
```

Comment: This is actually really strange that you see that 'pre-populated' values, since you return empty (new CompanyInput()) model as view result if model is not valid. Are you sure you posted right code sample?

Comment: @alexanerb Yes, my thoughts exactly. Yes, the code sample is correct. I find it strange as well.

Comment: check out the HTML, does the values of input initialized ??? It could be that browser is caching input fields, as well.

Comment: @alexanderb good shout, I'll run through a proxy and check it out.  However, I've noticed that if I do an `@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.CompanyName)` the value is cleared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ModelState of each field holds more than just the value, so removing it from the collection outright removed your error message as expected. I believe you should be able to clear just the value however, by doing something like.

```
ModelState["CompanyName"].Value = null;
```

**EDIT:** Upon closer inspection I found that the Value property is of type `ValueProviderResult`, simply nulling it doesn't give the desired result, and because the properties of this class appear to be getters only you have to replace the instance with your own. I've tested the following and it works for me.

```
ModelState["CompanyName"].Value = new ValueProviderResult(string.Empty, string.Empty, ModelState["CompanyName"].Value.Culture);
```

Comment: I just gave it a try.  This still shows me the *attempted* value that I typed in when the validation fails. Because I am using `@Html.EditorForModel`, I think I'm hitting the issue described here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1527149/3687407.aspx.  However, I'm wondering if there is something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Ahh sorry my bad. I didn't look closely enough and the datatype of the Value property. It's a `ValueProviderResult`. However the properties on this appear to be getters only. so you'll have to replace it with a new instance to get the behavior you want. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because the ModelState isn't valid, you will either have to create a custom validator or a jQuery ajax/json call to determine if the data needs to be cleared or not.

Just changing the model property to string.Empty or something like that won't do the trick because the entire view gets re-rendered with the previous successful posted model but with the ModelState validation errors.

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the problem.  So, would the custom validator reset the `RawValue` property?  How would this look?

Comment: Also, a jquery call (as far as I can tell) would still bring the input value back from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add error message like this

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "must be a string with a maximum length of 5")]
```

Update after clarity from OP:

To clear e.g. Input.Field = string.Empty;

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, sorry if I wasn't clear.  Even if I change the error message, the value I typed (that failed validation) will pre-populate in the text box.  I want to display the validation message, but clear the value in the text box (when validation fails).

Comment: Where do I put this code?  In my controller I get: `The property or indexer 'System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult.RawValue' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom validation class which is inherited from `ValidationAttribute` class
The following link gives a clear idea about how to implement custom validation class suitable for your problem.

[Custom Data Annotation](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/02/21/custom-data-annotation-validator-part-i-server-code.aspx)

Comment: Have you gotten this to work?  It doesn't work for me.  I think it is because of the reason explained here: http://forums.asp.net/p/1527149/3687407.aspx

Comment: I just tested it and it worked also, I test a codes in given link and it worked too. Also note that problem explained in forum is about MVC 2 Preview.

Comment: Strange, what version are you using? So, you see the validation message for string length appear, but the text box is empty?

Comment: Yes, I test both of them, a sample like your situation and another for problem explained in forum.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just can't get this to work.  Can you post your view?  I'll add the view I'm working with as well.  I'm using MVC 4.

Comment: Sorry My mistake, I Updated the post.